# In DynamoDB can you UpdateItem ignoring undefined values?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

DynamoDB is used to manage PATCH requests where 1 or more properties may be provided. I'd like those properties to be updated if they exist in the request, otherwise ignored in the update. `DocumentClient.update(params)` where `params` is:

```
    TableName: '...',
    Key: {...},
    UpdateExpression: `set 
      Cost = :Cost,
      Sales = :Sales,
      ...
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':Cost': get(requestBody, 'form.cost', undefined),
      ':Sales': get(requestBody, 'form.sales', undefined),
      ...
    }
```

Or is this achieving this only possible by [manipulating the expression strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52157337/3384225)?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I'm using DynamoDB wrong for this multi-field PATCH, especially since the solution is overly complex.

Leaving this here in case anyone else finds it helpful, or better, has a tidier solution:

```
  let fieldsToUpdate = [
    // these are just string constants from another file
    [dynamoDbFields.cost, apiFields.cost],
    [dynamoDbFields.annualSales, apiFields.annualSales],
    ... ]
    // get the new DynamoDB value from the request body (it may not exist)
    .map(([dynamoDbField, apiField]) => [dynamoDbField, _.get(requestBody, apiField)])
    // filter any keys that are undefined on the request body
    .filter(([dynamoDbField, value]) => value !== undefined)

  // create a mapping of the field identifier (positional index in this case) to the DynamoDB value, e.g. {':0': '123'}
  let expressionAttributeValues = fieldsToUpdate.reduce((acc, [dynamoDbField, value], index) =>
    _.assignIn(acc, {[`:${index}`]: value}), {})

  // and create the reciprocal mapping of the identifier to the DynamoDB field name, e.g {ID: ':0'}
  let updateExpression = fieldsToUpdate.reduce((acc, [dynamoDbField], index) =>
    _.assignIn(acc, {[dynamoDbField]: `:${index}`}), {})

  const params = {
    TableName: TABLE_NAME,
    Key: {[dynamoDbFields.id]: _.get(requestBody, apiFields.id)},
    UpdateExpression: `set ${Object.entries(updateExpression).map((v) => v.join('=')).join(',')}`,
    ExpressionAttributeValues: expressionAttributeValues,
    ConditionExpression: `attribute_exists(${dynamoDbFields.id})`,
    ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW'
  }
```